# Laravel: i can't send more then 2 variables from controller to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i am trying to send some query from the controller to a view but when try use the third variable it says:

> Undefined variable: type(View:)

The code i'm using is this in the controller :

```
    $doc=DB::table('documents')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'documents.id_user')
        ->join('type_docs', 'type_docs.id', '=', 'documents.id_tipo_doc')
        ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'documents.id_departamento')
        ->select('documents.*', 'type_docs.type', 'users.name','departments.abbreviation')
        ->get();
  $user=DB::table('users')
  ->select('users.*')
  ->get();
  $type=DB::table('type_docs')
  ->select('type_docs.*')
  ->get();


        //$doc = Document::all();
  return view('dashboard',['doc'=>$doc],['user'=>$user],['type'=>$type]);
```

and in the view:

```
       @foreach($type as $types)
                  <option value="{{$types->id}}">{{$types->type}}</option>
       @endforeach
```

Comment: Please read a manual again.

Answer (score 10):

You should return one array :

```
return view('dashboard',['doc'=>$doc,'user'=>$user,'type'=>$type]);
```

There is other ways such us :

```
return view('dashboard', array('doc'=>$doc,'user'=>$user,'type'=>$type));

return view('dashboard', compact('doc','user','type'));

return view('dashboard')
            ->with('doc', $doc)
            ->with('user', $user)
            ->with('type', $type);

return view('dashboard')            //using laravel Magic method.
            ->withDoc($doc)
            ->withUser($user)
            ->withType($type);
```

Comment: `return view('dashboard', compact('doc','user','type'));`

 should be array 

`return view('dashboard', compact( ['doc', 'user', 'type'] ));`

Comment: @ВилиславВенков according to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) ==> compact() takes a variable number of parameters. Each parameter can be either a string containing the name of the variable, or an array of variable names. The array can contain other arrays of variable names inside it; compact() handles it recursively.

Comment: @Maraboc, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @ВилиславВенков It's OK we all made mistakes and we learn from them ;)