# Best Way to return multiple variables to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an action method which has in its body multiple Variables something like this :-

```
$bus=Bus::all();
$user=User::all();
$employer=employer::all();
```

what am doing to return those variables objects to the view is using code like this

```
return view('create')->with(compact('bus', $bus))->with(compact('user', $user))->with(compact('employer', $employer));
```

is there a way a method or something to return this objects at once without the need for all of this code some thing like

```
return view('create')->($user,$bus,$emp);
```

just example of what i want .

Comment: `return view('create', compact('bus', 'user', 'employer'));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: i can't send more then 2 variables from controller to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377427/laravel-i-cant-send-more-then-2-variables-from-controller-to-a-view)

Comment: Thanks guys really appreciate ur answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create an array like this

```
$data['bus']=Bus::all();
$data['user']=User::all();
$data['employer']=employer::all();
return view('create',['data'=>$data]);
```

Comment: nice one :) but does this will return it in array as i need it to be return as json if i would make it for an api or something ?

Comment: @NasrAdin.if you print data it contain key value pair.so even in api its working properly

Comment: Yeah sure sry forgot :) thk again . @iCoders

Comment: @NasrAdin.glad to here .answer is helped

Comment: so bro when i want to access one of thie objects in the view , rather than using the variable for example $user->id i would use $user['data']->id ? thanks in advance

Comment: $data['user']->id this way you can access

Answer (score 6):

You have few options here.

**First approach is:**

Use `with()` and pass an array explicitly:

```
return view('create')->with('data', [
    'bus' => $bus, 
    'user' => $user,
    'employer' => $employer
]);
```

Use `with()` and list your variables in `compact()`:

```
return view('create')->with('data', compact('bus','user','employer'));
```

Your objects would be accessible in the view like an associative array $data with keys 'bus','user' and 'employer'.

**Another approach is:**

Pass an array as a second argument to `view()` function:

```
return view('create', [
    'bus' => $bus, 
    'user' => $user,
    'employer' => $employer
]);
```

Pass an `compact()` function (which would create an array like in the previous example behind the scenes) as a second argument to `view()` function:

```
return view('create', compact('bus','user','employer'));
```

If you use it this manner you will get three variables $bus, $user and $employer accessible in your view.

Answer (score 2):

You can do pretty much what you're after with

`return view('create', compact('bus', 'user', 'employer'));`

or do the `$data` option above