# Trying to pass data from controller to view in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to pass 2 different columns from my sql table to my view ,so that i can show them.
My controller is:

```
$interface = DB::table("users")->distinct()->get(['name']);
$interfac = DB::table("users")->distinct()->get(['email']);

        view()->share('users',compact('interface','interfac'));
```

My view is :

```
@foreach ($users as $key => $value)
<tr>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
 </tr>
```

But this is not working while passing the two variables.If i pass one it is working but passing two is not working.thanks.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377476/4881811)

Comment: Is it helping you ??

Comment: @gaan Do the other two variables are part of users array?

Comment: @Maraboc   sorry not working

Comment: @MortezaRajabi no

Comment: @gaan10 So, how users array created?

Comment: @MortezaRajabi check my view file ,i am trying to get the data from the users table

Comment: @gaan10 I see, but I don't find users collection creation in the controller.

Comment: I am unsure what your project is trying to do.

A `foreach` loop sorts one array. You're trying to display data from two arrays of data that may not be related.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

return view('users', compact('users'));
```

Comment: this won't work as the while displaying the values in the view.