# How do I pass data from my controller to a view in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a function that I'm trying to pass some data to a view.  I can't get the Route to recognize the data, it just keeps saying my variables are undefined.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
return redirect('confirm')->with([
   'name'=>$name,
   'service'=>$service,
   '$email_address'=>$email_address
]);
```

Then in my web.php file, I have:

```
Route::get ('confirm', function($name,$service,$email_address){

return view('confirm',compact('name','service','email_address'));
})->name('confirm');
```

Laravel just throws an error "Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}()"

I'm at a complete loss, I've tried this a bunch of different ways.  If I call the view right from my controller, it works fine, but then URL isn't what I want it to be, so it seems like I have to return the redirect and reference the data in my route definition.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377476/4881811) !

Comment: I can return the view in the Controller method and it uses the data just fine.  But then my URL is /oldurl instead of /confirm.

Comment: can you add the code before `return redirect('confirm')` how did you get the parameters ? can you sen just an id ?

Comment: $name, $service, and $email_address are just standard strings. They're all defined in the controller method when I call the redirect, I've tested to make sure.  But when I define the route in web.php, Laravel is reporting that I'm not passing anything to the route.

Comment: I asked you to add the controller code earlier but you didn't, just to see how we can adapt the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to show the email in the route then you can correct the problem like this :

```
Route::get ('confirm/{name}/{service}/{email_address}', function($name,$service,$email_address){
      return view('confirm',compact('name','service','email_address'));
})->name('confirm');
```

And in the controller :

```
return \Redirect::route('confirm', [
                                     'name'=>$name,
                                     'service'=>$service,
                                     'email_address'=>$email_address
                                  ]);
```

Ps : this is not recommended i just answer you problem but there is a better way to do it, passing just an id for exsample then find the user by id then take his email and other stuff.

Comment: Yes, I could do this as well, but as you said, this isn't the recommended way to do it, and it would make for a horrible URL.  Am I wrong in the understanding that it should be easy to pass parameters from the controller method to a redirect?