# laravel Undefined variable when i post multiple value to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In controller when i try to send multiple value to view such as this codes:

```
$content = Contents::find($contents);
$content_categories['categories'] = ContentCategories::all()->pluck('title', 'id');
$selected_categories['selected_categories'] = $content->categories()->pluck('title', 'id');

return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', compact($selected_categories, $content_categories, ['content' => $content]));
```

i get error for this variables into view:

```
$categories
$selected_categories
$content
```

result of `dd(['content' => $content], $content_categories, $selected_categories);` is:

```
array:1 [▼
  "content" => Contents {#220 ▶}
]

array:1 [▼
  "categories" => Collection {#214 ▶}
]

array:1 [▼
  "selected_categories" => Collection {#227 ▶}
]
```

whats problem of my code to parse them on view or send them with correct way

my view:

```
1) {{ Form::select('categories[]', $categories, $selected_categories, array('class' => 'multiselect-success','multiple'=>'multiple')) }}

2) action="{{ route('manage_contents.update' , ['id' => $content->id ]) }}"
```

Errors:

```
"Undefined variable: categories (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alachiqServer/resources/views/layouts/backend/pages/manage_contents/edit.blade.php)"

"Undefined variable: selected_categories (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alachiqServer/resources/views/layouts/backend/pages/manage_contents/edit.blade.php)"

"Undefined variable: content (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alachiqServer/resources/views/layouts/backend/pages/manage_contents/edit.blade.php)"
```

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: _compact() takes a variable number of parameters. Each parameter can be either a **string** containing the **name of the variable**, or an **array** of **variable names**. The array can contain other arrays of variable names inside it; compact() handles it recursively._ http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377476/4881811) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variables to the [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) without the `$` sign

```
$categories = ContentCategories::all()->pluck('title', 'id');
$selected_categories = $content->categories()->pluck('title', 'id');

return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', 
             compact('selected_categories', 'content_categories',
                     'content'));
```

Comment: i get this error:  `Undefined variable: categories`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$content_categories = ContentCategories::all()->pluck('title', 'id');
$selected_categories = $content->categories()->pluck('title', 'id');

return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', compact('selected_categories', 'content_categories', 'content'));
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Have you checked this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code something like this to pass value.

```
return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', compact('selected_categories', 'content_categories','content'));
```

Second point you getting undefined $categories because you are not passing categories into compact function. you need to pass categories variable into compact function.

I think you need to change select tag code like this:

```
{{ Form::select('categories[]', $selected_categories['categories'], NULL , array('class' => 'multiselect-success','multiple'=>'multiple')) }}
```

Hope can help you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$content = Contents::find($contents);
$categories = ContentCategories::all()->pluck('title', 'id');
$selected_categories = $content->categories()->pluck('title', 'id');

return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', compact($selected_categories, $content_categories, $content));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
return view('layouts.backend.pages.manage_contents.edit', compact('selected_categories', 'content_categories', 'content'));
```