# Notification with route

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, routes

I have small problem with route laravel.
My goal is display notif toaster after save data. I use with code and It's ready but if refresh my web page, data store again.

```
return view('backend.pages.product_list', compact('product_list'));
```

And I use this code in use route and not display notif after save data

```
$notif = array('message' => 'Save success','type' => 'success');
return redirect('admin/product')->with('notif);
```

In the view i use this code :

```
<script> 
    @if(isset($notif['message'])) 
        var type = "{{ $notif['type'] }}"; 
        switch(type){ 
            case 'info': 
                toastr.info("{{ $notif['message'] }}"); 
                break; 
            case 'warning': 
                toastr.warning("{{ $notif['message'] }}"); 
                break; 
            case 'success': 
                toastr.success("{{ $notif['message'] }}"); 
                break; 
            case 'error': 
                toastr.error("{{ $notif['message'] }}"); 
                break; 
        } 
    @endif 
</script>
```

If you have idea, thank you

Comment: There is an error in the `with` statment , it should be like this : `return redirect('admin/product')->with('notif', $notif)` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377476/4881811) for more examples

Comment: @Maraboc I use return redirect('admin/product')->with('notif', $notif) but nothing change. Notif don't display. If I use with return view('backend.pages.product_list', compact('product_list')); so the code run

Comment: can you shwo as the part of the view that displays the notif message ?

Comment: <script>
      @if(isset($notif['message']))
        var type = "{{ $notif['type'] }}";
        switch(type){
            case 'info':
                toastr.info("{{ $notif['message'] }}");
                break;

            case 'warning':
                toastr.warning("{{ $notif['message'] }}");
                break;

            case 'success':
                toastr.success("{{ $notif['message'] }}");
                break;

            case 'error':
                toastr.error("{{ $notif['message'] }}");
                break;
        }
      @endif
    </script>

Comment: Try a simple code like this `redirect('admin/product')->with('success', 'Save success')` and in the view use `@if(session()->has('success'))
    {!! session()->get('success') !!}
@endif` and test ?

Comment: Its ready but how to integrate with my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161713/discussion-between-maraboc-and-tojo-rodialson).

Comment: Its solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with code `return redirect('Your route name')->with('success', 'Data saved success');`