# Laravel 5 how to pass single variable from controller and catch the same in blade view file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have passed $id from the controller as:

```
$data['getId'] = $id; // say value = 12
return view('Administrator.notification.index',$data);
```

However, in the view file when I used `{{getId}}` , it show me the error:

> Use of undefined constant getId - assumed 'getId'

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377476/4881811)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$data` variable is acessible from the view, not `getId`. `$data` is an array, `getId` is a key of the `$data` array and 12 your value according to the key value.

Try printing out something like: `{{$data['getId']}}`

If you want to see the output of the variable, for debugging purposes, use `{{dd($data)}}`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views

Comment: But if the $data has other variables like $data['myvar'] = Model::function(); and I want to use the getId in my form then? My intention is to use the getId as a variable, not as in dd();

Comment: DD is a sort of print and kill method. Just do {{data['getId']}}.

Answer (score 1):

update this line from

```
return view('Administrator.notification.index',$data);
```

To

```
return view('Administrator.notification.index',compact('data'));
```

and then in view u can access it like this,

```
{{ $data['getId'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is you are missing the `$` sign. It's `{{$getId}}` not `{{getId}}`.

Comment: it is `{{getId}}` not `{{$getId}}`